# App name with superscript text android

Tags: android, superscript

I want to name my android application with a super script
like (UNO ™ ). As you see the tm is smaller and up of the line.

I used `Html.fromHtml(X +"<sup><font style=\"font-size:1;\">TM</font ></sup>"));`

Also in strings.xml I used `<string name="app_name"> X<sup><font style="font-size:1;">TM</font></sup> </string>`

Also it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: For this particular case, try using the Unicode trademark symbol.  This would be `"\u2122"` in Java code, `&#x2122;` in your strings file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use unicode symbol [Trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol) instead.

```
<string name="app_name"> Your name &#8482;</string>
```

where `&#8482;` is ™